# Maximum lag length for serial correlation test on VAR residuals

Tags: time-series, model-selection, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression, lags

I do have a dataset with monthly data. I apply

```
serial.test(VAR,lags.pt=12, lags.bg=12, type="both")
```

from the `vars` package to test for serial correlation in the residuals.

Considering that the data is a *monthly* time series, with a total of 72 observations (06/2006 - 06/20012), is using a maximum lag of 12 appropriate? Some literature states that the lag length should reflect the seasonality of data.

```
VARselect(VAR,lag.max = 12,type="both")
```

proposes 1 or 4. I subsequently look with above mentioned `serial.test` for the best fit and wonder which lag to use here.

I assume that I should select the same lag length for the test for serial correlation, as for the `VARselect` model fit itself, in order to relate my analysis of serial correlation to the same type of data?

Comment: I suppose you are testing autocorrelation (a.k.a. serial correlation) rather than stability.

Comment: See ["Thoughts on the Ljung-Box test"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ljung-box-test/) by Rob J. Hyndman.

Comment: Agree, sorry. I am testing autocorrelation.

Comment: @RichardHardy isn't the Box.test only suitable for univariate time series?

Comment: Considering the link in the Ljung Box test, h would be "24" (2x12 (m)). Given that the whole time series is only 72 obs. I think 12 is okay then.

Comment: Hmm, probably so.